# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select a specific module in the project window?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I can't use screen shots (too much proprietary information in those), so I will to explain this UI problem via text.

My IntelliJ project has 3 modules, so the project window shows

```
A
B
C
```

My workflow requires me to do:

- edit a file X belonging to module A
- trigger an action on module B

In order to do that, I click into the edit window for X (which is open all the time) and make my change. Then I click on the line for module B in the project window (to then invoke a specific context menu action from a 3rd party plugin).

Thing is: I defined a key stroke that invokes that 3rd party plugin action. But in order for the key stroke to work, the B module needs to be "selected" somehow. ( and it is **not** selected currently, because I have to edit a file that belongs to module A )

In other words: I can do all my work using the keyboard, but I have to reach to the mouse to get the "focus" from the A.X editor window to the B module line in the project view.

Is there a way to get there without using the mouse?

Comment: BTW, I would also like to know how to switch to the previous project using the keyboard

Comment: Did you try bookmarks? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-bookmarks.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the Project window. The shortcut depends on the OS but you can find it into the keymap menu: "Tool Windows" > Project.

After that just start typing the module name, the focus will move.

Comment: So simple. And for the record, on MacOs, the shortcut is command-1. Thanks!